# How to represent a bitmask using DebuggerDisplay attribute

Tags: c#

I have a class with 8 bool's, and I want to represent those bools as 1 or 0 in the debugger, how can I achieve this?

Comment: can't you view them as true/false in the debugger?

Comment: Do you have 8 `bool` fields or an array of `bool`s?

Comment: Its a class with 8 properties, that are bool, there is also an index to access it as obj[0-7] = true.

Comment: @stakx It's usage of a C# attribute that comes with BCL.

Answer (score 2):

Yo can create a simple helper method:

```
private string GetBitMask(params bool[] values)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        sb.Append(value ? "1" : "0");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{GetBitMask(flag1, flag8)}")]
public class YouClass
{
    private bool flag1;
    // ...
    private bool flag8;
}
```

Or, in case you have an array of `bool`s:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{GetBitMask(flags)}")]
public class YouClass
{
    private bool[] flags;
    // ...
}
```

**EDIT:** if you can't/don't want to modify your original class, then move `GetBitMask()` to some utility class, make it `static` and use it from any place you want:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Utils.GetBitMask(flags)}")]
```